# make error at compile

Tags: make, cmake

I want to compile dsd from [github](https://github.com/szechyjs/dsd).
Requirements are :

- cmake
- mbelib
- sndfile
- itpp (IT++) >= v4.3
- portaudio (optional, improves audio support)

Every thing is ok except itpp package. Because it's version in my Ubuntu 4.2.1 (its installed with: `sudo apt-get install libitpp-dev`.
How I can to upgrade it?

make gives error during compile:

```
cmakefiles/dsd.dir/src/p25p1_check_nid.cpp.o: In function 'check_NID':p25p1_check_nid.cpp:(.text+0xc1): undefined refrence to 'itpp::BCH::decode(itpp::vec<itpp::bin> const&, itpp::vec<itpp::bin>&, itpp::vec<itpp::bin>&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dsd] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CmakeFiles/dsd.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running? Version v4.3 comes with every release from 14.04 (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libitpp-dev).

Comment: @Jos It's ubuntu 12.4.5 64

Comment: I upgrade the itpp to 4.3.1 .... but yet give previous error

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your build of `itpp-4.3.1` you will have to remove the Ubuntu 12.04 itpp version : `sudo apt-get remove libitpp-dev libitpp7`

`cd dsd/build/ && cmake ../ && make` : No errors, Ubuntu 12.4.5 - 64.

Comment: i try that you say.... first remove libitpp-dev and libitpp7 and make dsd... but this time error is: fatal error: itpp/itcomm.h: No such file or directory